# Google index result only on mobile

Tags: google, google-index

I was checking my Google webmaster, saw that my website is indexed on page 3.
Whenever  check this on desktop it showes nothing of my websites on page 1 to 5.
But strangely I found out that it's showing up whenever I use mobile or the emulation mode.

How can this be, can someone explain me?

Comment: Because mobile results are not the same as desktop results. If your higher on mobile its because it favors your site and content on the mobile. Hence your rank higher.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume you have two versions of your website from one URL and the desktop version has been hacked.

Check your *.htaccess* file and look for lines that detect for mobile devices. If they are present, then there will be redirection going on if the device in question isn't of the correct type.

Code to look for can be found by selecting any of the applicable blue buttons at:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Here's a layman example of what I mean:

Suppose there are two versions of your website. The desktop version at `d.example.com` and the mobile version at `m.example.com`. Also, assume both `d.example.com` and `m.example.com` consist of content formatted correctly for the desktop screen and the mobile screen respectively.

Suppose you are using a mobile device to access `example.com`. The server detects your device to be mobile and thus directs you to `m.example.com` which displays the correct content.

Later someone uses the desktop computer to access `example.com`. They are then forwarded to `d.example.com`.

At some point later, a hacker accessed your script and changed the website link of the desktop version to `h.example.com` and `h.example.com` contains gibberish.

Now all users with desktop computers who access `example.com` will be redirected to gibberish while users with mobile computers will be redirected to `m.example.com`, the properly formatted site for mobile users.

As you may be aware, gibberish will never rank well unless the most awkward characters (that don't even spell English words) are searched for.